# Transform listener can't find base_link

Tags: transforms, ros-fuerte, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to read values from base_link frame in order to get my robot's coordinates with the following code:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
try {
        listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/odom", ros::Time(0),
                transform);
    } catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
        ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
    }
```

However, all I get is an error.

> [ERROR] [1394401426.907398394,
> 36.516000000]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! Frames (1)

I can visualize base_link in rviz or read it's values on terminal using rostopic echo so I'm pretty sure it exists.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137631/transform-listener-can%27t-find-base_link/) by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding this line solved the problem:

```
listener.waitForTransform("base_link", "odom", ros::Time(0),
            ros::Duration(3.0));
```

so the final code is:

```
try {

    listener.waitForTransform("base_link", "odom", ros::Time(0),
            ros::Duration(3.0));
    listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/odom", ros::Time(0),
            transform);
} catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
    ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
}
```

---

Originally posted by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) with karma: 35 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-09**:
Please mark your own answer as correct if it is.

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on 2014-03-11**:
It says I need more than 25 points for that.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-11**:
Now you have 25 karma.